# How to render a link with a query string in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am trying to generate a link field on to the page, in the below format

```
<a class="book__btn" href="https://oc.axis.com/rez.aspx?submit=&shell=CASGCF">
Book
</a>
```

**aspx:**

```
<sc:Link ID="lnkBook" runat="server" Field="Target URL"></sc:Link>
<sc:FieldRenderer ID="frBook" runat="server" FieldName="Target URL"></sc:FieldRenderer>
```

**aspx.cs:**

```
Item offerDetails = this.DataSource;
lnkBook.Item = offerDetails;
frBook.Item = offerDetails;
```

The pic shows my declarations using Rocks
[image]

When the page is previewed, the button does not render at all. However, if I remove the text in the `Query String` field, it renders fine.

Comment: What is the value of query string? looks to be wrong

Comment: Yes, the url is a bit weird but when I browse it, the other page opens fine.

Answer (score 1):

The Sitecore Rocks interface is a little misleading for links because the applicable fields do not change based on the link type. `Query String` is only supported for internal links. If you want to add a query string to your external link, just add it directly to the `Url`.

Comment: Tried that too. did not work. Is there any other alternate for this scenario

Comment: Switch to Raw Values, clear it out, and use the UI? Link field can easily have subsequent parse issues when using Rocks.